# Force Mobile browsers to display webpage at its native resolution

Tags: html, ios, css

I am building a responsive website which will be running on smartphones like iPhone having high pixel density screens. I know that in order to maintain legibility, mobile phones' browsers report a resolution half that of actual screen resolution.

I searched about this and found that this behavior can be controlled by using css media query of device pixel ratio (for e.g. @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) ) for iPhone.
I tried using this by putting my entire css code within this block, but my iPhone still displayed the page exactly as it was displaying it without using this media query.

How can I force iPhone and other high pixel density mobile phones to display my webpage at its actual resolution? i.e. for iPhone 5, it should display my webpage at 640px*1136px and not 320px*568px as it is now showing. I know that this will make my text appear smaller, but I still wish to format my webpage like that.

I am using the following meta code in my HTML:-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Putting your CSS rules in the media query doesn't affect how the browser renders it, if you don't change the CSS rules. You could try with something like this:

```
.element {
    width: 100px;
}

@media -webkit-device-min-pixel-ratio: 2 {
    .element {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
```

Basically you can explicitly double the size when the device pixel ratio is double.  Unfortunately with this technique you have to use a different media query with different sizes for all possible pixel ratio that you have to deal with.

Otherwise you can play with the width attribute of the viewport meta tag. If your page has a fixed-width layout, you can set its width as viewport width. For example if you have use a "standard" with of 960px, you can use the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=960px">
```